# solr terms returns nil

Tags: search, solr, frequency

I am running solr `7.2.1` version, using `SolrCloud` with a collection based on the example configuration. `lucene` part of the configuration (`http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/info/system?wt=yaml`) is

```
solr-spec-version   "7.2.1"
solr-impl-version   "7.2.1 b2b6438b37073bee1fca40374e85bf91aa457c0b - ubuntu - 2018-01-10 00:54:21"
lucene-spec-version "7.2.1"
lucene-impl-version "7.2.1 b2b6438b37073bee1fca40374e85bf91aa457c0b - ubuntu - 2018-01-10 00:48:43"
```

The terms configuration (`http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/config?wt=yaml`)is:

```
name    "terms"
class   "solr.TermsComponent"
```

The `http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/terms?wt=xml` returns:

```
<lst name="/terms">
  <str name="startup">lazy</str>
  <str name="name">/terms</str>
  <str name="class">solr.SearchHandler</str>
  <lst name="defaults">
    <bool name="terms">true</bool>
    <bool name="distrib">false</bool>
  </lst><arr name="components"><str>terms</str></arr>
</lst>
```

Although there are 1K documents in the collection (`http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/query?q=*:*&rows=0`, 2MB of text):

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":4,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "rows":"0"}},
  "response":{"numFound":978,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[]
  }}
```

How can I see get the terms (and their frequencies)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to use the terms component to get all terms for a field, you have to include [the field you want the terms for](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/the-terms-component.html#TheTermsComponent-TermsComponentParameters):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/trans/terms?terms.fl=fieldname&wt=xml
```